# Python: Project with multiple packages, but I'd like to have one config file

Tags: python, setup-project, directory-structure

I have a project that I will distribute that will contain several sub-packages. One for cleaning data, one for transforming data, and another for calculating some statistics. I'd like to avoid having a 3 config.py files, can I just put a config.py file in the top level? For example, instead of doing this:

```
MyPackage
|
├──mypackage
|     |
|     ├── __init__.py
|     |
|     ├── data_clean
|     |   ├── __init__.py
|     |   ├── config.py
|     |   └── f1.py
|     |
|     ├── data_transform
|     |   ├── __init__.py
|     |   ├── config.py
|     |   └── g1.py
|     |
|     └── stat_calc
|        ├── __init__.py
|        ├── config.py
|        ├── s1.py
|        └── command_line_interface.py # <- users will use this from cmd.exe
|      
├── README.txt    
|
└── setup.py
```

I would like to have:

```
MyPackage
|
├──mypackage
|     |
|     ├── __init__.py
|     |
|     ├── config.py  # <---- put all 3 config.py stuff into here
|     |
|     ├── data_clean
|     |   ├── __init__.py
|     |   └── f1.py
|     |
|     ├── data_transform
|     |   ├── __init__.py
|     |   └── g1.py
|     |
|     └── stat_calc
|         ├── __init__.py
|         ├── s1.py
|         └── command_line_interface.py # <- users will use this from cmd.exe
| 
├── README.txt    
|
└── setup.py
```

Would this make sense and is this pythonic/correct?

Comment: Are your users expected to do `import mypackage`, `import mypackage.data_clean`, etc. or just `import data_clean`?  If the former, your README and `setup.py` need to be moved outside `mypackage`.  If the latter, `mypackage/__init__.py` should be deleted.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to mention `command_line_interface.py`. Users will open command prompt and do `python C:/users/user/MyPackage/mypackage/stat_calc/command_line_interface.py arg1`. This is the only access users will have to the code. But to answer your question (kind of) `command_line_interface.py` will import functions from `data_clean/f1.py` and `data_transform/g1.py` and `stat_calc/s1.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your module will be stored in the PYTHONPATH, the answer is yes. Just import it:

from MyPackage import config